# Why is $s$ used for arc length?

Tags: trigonometry, differential-geometry, soft-question, notation, math-history

Why is $s$ used for arc length? I looked around online, but I can't find a definite answer.

Thank you!

Comment: I think it's a convenient letter to use because it "works like $t$, but isn't quite $t$", and $s$ comes alphabetically before $t$.  $t$, of course, is used because "time" starts with a $t$.

Comment: Is there an actual reason, though?

Comment: I assumed it was related to displacement and SUVAT but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Not that I know of.  There's an interesting quick ted talk about why $x$ is commonly used as a variable.  History is weird.

Comment: I've seen that too. Is there a definite answer?

Comment: In differential geometry we calculate the distance between two points using things called line elements which are denoted $d{s}$. So the total length of a curve can be denoted $s = \int\limits_{curve} {ds} $.

Comment: @Karl but that's just answering questions with more questions: why would the physicists use $s$ as their go-to displacement variable?  Alphabetic proximity as a reason is still my best guess.

Comment: I've always assumed $s$ to stand for "segment" (as in "line segment"). That said, I don't have any sources to back up my case.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  I looked up displacement and it's spatium in latin if that helps. It was just a thought.

Comment: Surprisingly, there's no answer in Cajori's *History of Mathematical Notations*.

Comment: @Karl I like the Latin idea. Is there any evidence for that? Thanks!

Comment: @Thanksinadvantage sorry I can't confirm it for you unfortunately. It was just the thought that came to me.  I'd be interested in seeing the correct answer if there is one.

Comment: @Karl That's okay! I'm going to do a bit of research on all of these theories...

Comment: The same way as "distance"  and other notions are extensions or generalizations of properties in $\mathbb R$ the notion of "arc" certainly generalizes the notion of "segment" in a line. Furthermore "segment" in English is very similar as a word to the equivalent in German, French,Italian, Spanish and Latin. I am convinced that @White Shirt was right in his Assumption about this notation.

Comment: Because using $d$ for displacement would just look stupid.$$\int dd$$

Comment: I bet it comes from German *Strecke* or Latin *spatium* meaning *distance*.

Comment: In physics we often parametrize curves by arc length, and say that two points on the curve are *separated* by $s$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I strongly agree with Karl's and Björn's comments regarding the Latin orgin: *spatium*.

See: Leonhard Euler, [Mechanica sive motus scientia analytice exposita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanica), Tomus I, Petropoli, 1736 :

> **Propositio 4** [ [page 13](https://books.google.it/books?id=jgdTAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA13) ] Sit *spatium* $AM$, sive sit linea recta sive curva, $=s$, et celeritas, quam corpus habet in M sit $c$, quae erit functio quaedam ipsius $s$. Ab $M$ accipiatur elementum $Mm$, quod igitur motu aequabili idque celeritate $c$ percurri concipiendum est. Vocato elemento $Mm$, $ds$; erit tempus quo hoc elementum pe[r]curritur $=\frac{ds}{c}$. Integrando ergo habebitur tempus, quo totus arcus $AM$ absolvitur $=\int\frac{ds}{c}$.

Comment: This, along with its relation to other languages, makes me feel like this is the correct answer! Thanks!